# Still hitting certificate error after configure mobileFirst keystore

Tags: java, android, ssl, keystore, mfp

Good day,

I have a MobileFirst Server, that will call to my bankend appliction (ip address: 10.8.1.46).

Its work currently as I am connected to http backend application.

I would like to change it to connect to `https`.

The following is the step I have done:

1. Log in to bakend server, run the following command to generate the keystore:

   keytool -genkey -alias backend -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore backend.jks -storetype JKS

It prompt to key in keystore password, first name and last name and the other info.
For first name and last name, I key in `10.8.1.46`

2. I run the following command to export the `crt` file"

   keytool -export -alias backend -keystore backend.keystore -rfc -file backend.crt
3. I copy this `backend.crt` to my `mfp` server. In my mfp server, I also create a keystore, by following command:

   keytool -keystore mfp.jks -genkey -alias mfp -keyalg RSA
4. I run the following command to import the backend cert to mfp keystore.

   keytool -import -alias backend -file backend.crt -storetype JKS -keystore mfp.jks
5. I run the keytool command to verify the cert is inside the keystore or not, and yes, its inside.

   keytool -list -keystore mfp.jks
6. Next, I go edit mfp server `server.xml`, I update the keystore tag as follow:

   `<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/opt/IBM/libertyCore/usr/servers/mfp1/resources/security/mfp.jks" password="pass123" type="jks" />`
7. And I added in the `<connectivity>` tag in my adapter.xml:

```
<displayName>MyAdapter</displayName>
<description>MyAdapter</description>

<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>10.8.1.46</domain>
        <port>8443</port>
        <sslCertificateAlias>mfp</sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword>pass123</sslCertificatePassword>    
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<JAXRSApplicationClass>c.c.i.mobile.MyAdapterApplication</JAXRSApplicationClass>

<property name="rest.api.base.url" defaultValue="https://10.8.1.46:8443/api/v1" description="REST API Base URL" />

<property name="rest.api.connection.request.timeout" defaultValue="4000" description="REST API Connection Request Timeout (miliseconds)" />

<property name="rest.api.connect.timeout" defaultValue="10000" description="REST API Connect Timeout (miliseconds)" />

<property name="rest.api.socket.timeout" defaultValue="50000" description="REST API Socket Timeout (miliseconds)" />

<securityCheckDefinition name="UserAuthentication" class="c.c.i.mobile.authentication.UserAuthentication">

    <property name="maxAttempts" defaultValue="3" description="How many attempts are allowed"/>

</securityCheckDefinition>
```

8. restart mfp server.

However, I am still hitting certificate error when fire request to https backend service.

```
[2/20/20 18:56:37:900 MYT] 0000008c c.c.i.mobile.resources.GeneralResource                  I >>> initialize
[2/20/20 18:56:37:906 MYT] 0000008c c.c.i.mobile.client.RestClient                          E client fail to execute REST
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at com.cv.ibs.mobile.client.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:55)
        at com.cv.ibs.mobile.resources.BaseResource.requestForPost(BaseResource.java:47)
        at com.cv.ibs.mobile.resources.GeneralResource.initialize(GeneralResource.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox$3.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:579)
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:584)
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.rest.AdaptersEndpoint.adapterServing(AdaptersEndpoint.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 83 more
```

But if go to MFP Console to change the url back to http, its still work.

Is there any steps I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the mfp.jks is not load by server.xml even restart mfp server.

I found another alternative way to do this, by add the following value into jvm.options in mfp server:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/IBM/libertyCore/usr/servers/mfp1/resources/security/mfp.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=cyber123
```

Restart mfp server and it will work.